# iOS external display not filling screen

Tags: ios, swift

My app displays images / videos on an external display via thunderbolt to HDMI adapter. Works fine except the screen does not fill. There is some sort of margin frame I can't figure out how to get rid of. It is equal, about 50px, top, bottom, left, right..  Here's the code for images:

```
func addImage(image: UIImage){
    if UIScreen.screens().count > 1 {
        let secondScreen = UIScreen.screens()[1]
        secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: secondScreen.bounds)
        print(secondScreen.bounds) // 1920x1080
        //secondWindow?.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) // Tried.. no change
        secondWindow?.screen = secondScreen
        secondScreenView = UIView(frame: secondWindow!.frame)
        //secondScreenView?.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0) // Tried.. no change
        secondWindow?.addSubview(secondScreenView!)
        secondWindow?.hidden = false

        externalImage = UIImageView(frame: secondScreen.bounds)

        externalImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit // Tried .ScaleAspectFill
        externalImage.image = image

        secondScreenView!.addSubview(externalImage)
    }else{
        noExternalDisplay()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!!

```
secondScreen.overscanCompensation = UIScreenOverscanCompensation(rawValue: 3)!
```

Comment: Does not seem to work anymore. Tried `newScreen.overscanCompensation = UIScreen.OverscanCompensation.none` but what ever I set it to, it will always reflect the `UIScreen.OverscanCompensationInsets` on the screen. (using an iPhone11 + 1920x1080 Screen) Any ideas?